# Should Windows reference assemblies be copied to solution tree (C#, WPF app)?

Tags: c#, dll, windows-runtime, .net-assembly, projects-and-solutions

I have traditionally kept all DLL dependencies under version control and in a folder (file system) in the development tree (e.g., Main\Lib or Source\ThirdParty).

I inherited a C# WPF desktop application solution with multiple projects, one of which depends on a Windows "Reference Assembly" `(C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\ v4.5.1\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll).`

The reference in the C# project (*.csproj file) is an absolute path to the reference assembly.  Usually I avoid this because I want the source code tree to be everything needed to build the application and I do not want the source tree to depend on the developer's environment.  (I even prefer avoiding NuGet packages but that is a bit of a separate matter.)

Should I loosen up this long-used strategy in the case of "reference assemblies"?  Or would it make sense to copy reference assemblies into the source tree?

Comment: well.. I would say it depends :-) I would suggest you to read following article which will explain some sort of things related to your question: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx . If you will have more question after reading this please ask

Comment: Using a copy of these reference assemblies is certainly a very bad idea.  They are the one way that Microsoft ensures that future changes to the framework don't break old code.  Or in other words, a future VS version or Developer Pack might well update it.  Whether this assembly is still around a decade from now is hard to guess.  It is an old version of .NETCore, the one before it was made open-source and the version number got reset back to 1.0.  WinRT apps used it.  A backup copy is perhaps not a bad idea, just a backup.

Comment: So, these reference assemblies (in Program Files tree) are not fixed/stable?  They can change?
(I had understood them to be intentionally stable for the versioning issue you described.  That's the bit I was missing I believe.)

Comment: I am really just trying to adjust my long-adhered-to (multi-platform, multi-language, multi-IDE, multi-decade) practice of always keeping dependencies in the source tree.  I guess the rationale here is that these assemblies are foundational/framework (different than more ephemeral third-party libraries).